# DataPager for WPF3.5?

Tags: wpf, datapager

I'd like to know if there is any free custom control DataPager for WPF3.5?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am also want the answer for this question,

Comment: i was looking for WPF4 SataPager control  some thing like available in Silverlight 4/Silverlight 4 tool kit Apr-2010